# Deserialize JSON with ID as object name (string)

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm creating a client for the Philips Hue bridge, where a list of lights has me stumped. The JSON returned rom the web API looks like the below sample (adjusted for simplicity). My question is simply, how can I deserialize this to a List (or similar) in C#? It seems to me the JSON returned should be an array, but annoyingly it is not. Any input is greatly appreciated!

```
{
    "2": {
        "state": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 254,
            "hue": 14987,
            "sat": 141,
            "effect": "none",
            "xy": [
                0.4573,
                0.41
            ],
            "ct": 366,
            "alert": "select",
            "colormode": "ct",
            "mode": "homeautomation",
            "reachable": false
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "state": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 254,
            "hue": 14987,
            "sat": 141,
            "effect": "none",
            "xy": [
                0.4573,
                0.41
            ],
            "ct": 366,
            "alert": "select",
            "colormode": "ct",
            "mode": "homeautomation",
            "reachable": false
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding brackets ([]) to make the objects an array, but had no luck in deserializing.

Comment: Try with a dictionary. But may depend on the json lib that is in use.

Comment: Deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, T>` as shown in [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) (for Json.NET) and [How to deserialize objects having different keys (names) but identical structure in C# .Net 8 using System.Text.Json.Serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77512477/3744182) (for System.Text.Json).  Assuming you are using one of those serializers, this looks to be a duplicate.  Which serializer are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213566/create-a-strongly-typed-c-sharp-object-from-json-object-with-id-as-the-name)

Answer (score 0):

if you need an array you will have to parse your json at first, and after to use select to convert to array

```
State[] states = JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
                              .Select(i => i.Value["state"].ToObject<State>())
                              .ToArray();
 
public class State
{
    public bool on {get; set;}

    //another properties
}
```

or if you need an Index too

```
StateItem[] states = JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
                              .Select(i => new StateItem { index = i.Name, 
                                                state = i.Value.ToObject<State>()})
                              .ToArray();
public class StateItem
{  
    public string index {get; set;}
    public State state {get; set;}
}
public class State
{
    public bool on {get; set;}

    //another properties
}
```